# Draftwatermark with inserted PDF

Tags: pdfpages, watermark, draftwatermark

I have included a watermark (using `\usepackage{draftwatermark}`) for draft copies of my document, several pages of which are inserted from a PDF. The watermark behaves just fine on most pages  - the watermark is obscured by text and inline images, as expected/desired - but on the inserted PDF, the watermark obscures the data.

Is this just due to how Latex inserts PDFs? Is there a way to make the inserted PDF show above the draftwatermark?

Comment: You can define a switch for draftwatermark. It is explained here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76141/draft-watermark-image-just-in-a-section

Comment: @user25241: The switch only turns the watermark on and off, it doesn't make it appear underneath the text.

Answer (score 5):

I achieved this by replacing this:

```
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkLightness{0.93}
```

With this:

```
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
    \AtTextCenter{%
        \makebox[0pt]{%
            \scalebox{14}{%
                \rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{%
                    \color[gray]{.93}\normalfont DRAFT}}}}}
```

Which I found [on a forum post](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/tMRBZDaLGbr3hWI9UIb4).

Now the words "DRAFT" appear behind the text in inserted PDF pages, so you can properly read the text of the inserted PDF.

Comment: Do not forget the `\usepackage{eso-pic}` where `\AddToShipoutPicture` is defined.

Answer (score 4):

I recommended to use [`pdftk`](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) for such things. If `watermark.pdf` is the watermark and `mydocument.pdf` is the (may be LaTeX generated) own document, you can can "watermark" it:

```
pdftk mydocument.pdf background watermark.pdf output mydocumentdraft.pdf
```