# Is it possible to add watermark to an existing pdf with tex, latex?

Tags: pdf

I saved a web page as a pdf.

I would like to add watermark to this existing pdf.

I googled and got some answers either using something like Adobe Acrobat DC or using a programming language like Python.

Is it feasible to add watermark to this existing pdf within tex, latex?

Comment: Why would you need to do this in (La)TeX when you have free online options to achieve the same?

Comment: @manooooh because those kind of tools ask me to provide an image rather than a latex code, which leads that I can not design the watermark directly and efficiently. would you please provide a free online tool that support latex?

Comment: You can import an existing pdf using `pdfpages`, check this out https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76180/draftwatermark-with-inserted-pdf