# is it possible use latex to generate a pdf that only contains watermark without any other additional characters?

Tags: watermark

I saved a web page as a pdf.

I would like to add watermark to this existing pdf.

I googled and got an approach that suggest to merge 2 pdf, the original one and the one contains watermark.

this code could used to generate a watermark pdf

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox\mybox
\newwatermark*[
  allpages,
  angle=45,
  scale=6,
  xpos=-20,
  ypos=15
]{\usebox\mybox}

\begin{document}

\savebox\mybox{\tikz[color=red,opacity=0.3]\node{DRAFT};}

ab

\end{document}
```

although there have to be some additional characters ("ab" in this case).

is it possible use latex to generate a pdf that only contains watermark without any other additional characters?

Comment: Replace `ab` by `~`, for instance.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat  Thanks a lot! Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I think if your problem is solved, all is fine. What I want to say is that I will be happy to write an answer if you think that will be useful for others, but if you only want to solve the issue then I may not.  BTW, you do not need to load `graphicx` nor `xcolor` here`, and probably want to add `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}` to remove the navigation symbols on the bottom right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code overlays pages 3 and 4 of the `pdfpages` manual with a red "DRAFT" watermark:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\filename}{/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf}
\newcommand{\watermark}{\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \node [red,opacity=0.3,rotate=45,scale=15.0] at (current page.center) {DRAFT};}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=3-4,pagecommand={\watermark}]{\filename}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I use the `pdfpages` package and its macro `\includepdf` to include an external PDF file:

- The mandatory argument takes the filename of the external file. In this example, I use the absolute path of the `pdfpages` manual. You can replace this by the name of your PDF file, and give the relative path instead - i.e. just the filename if the PDF is in the same folder as the LaTeX file.
- The optional argument `pages` takes the range of pages of the PDF to be included in the output file.
- The optional argument `pagecommand` takes some code to be executed on top of each page. Here, I use `tikz` to overlay the included pages of the PDF with the word "DRAFT" in red, semi-transparent, rotated, and scaled to a large size. Adjust this as needed.

---

<sub>This is not exactly an answer to the question as stated, but I think it answers the issue you want to achieve if we also consider what you wrote in the [other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516749/is-it-possible-to-add-watermark-to-an-existing-pdf-with-tex-latex?noredirect=1&lq=1) which we just closed as a duplicate.</sub>