# how to remove bottom toolbar at footer in a generated pdf?

Tags: header-footer

This code generates a pdf with watermark, with additional toolbar at footer pointed out by the blue arrow.

how to remove that toolbar?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newsavebox\mybox
\newwatermark*[
  allpages,
  angle=45,
  scale=6,
  xpos=-20,
  ypos=15
]{\usebox\mybox}

\begin{document}

\savebox\mybox{\tikz[color=red,opacity=0.3]\node{DRAFT};}

~

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}`, as mentioned [in my previous comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516750/is-it-possible-use-latex-to-generate-a-pdf-that-only-contains-watermark-without#comment1306725_516750).

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat  Thanks a lot! Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, these are my comments combined. One out of many ways of getting an empty slide is to add a `~` for the comment. Then add `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}` to suppress the navigation symbols, and you do not need to load `\usepackage{xcolor}` nor `\usepackage{graphicx}` because they get already loaded by `beamer` (and `tikz`).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newsavebox\mybox
\newwatermark*[
  allpages,
  angle=45,
  scale=6,
  xpos=-20,
  ypos=15
]{\usebox\mybox}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}

\savebox\mybox{\tikz[color=red,opacity=0.3]\node{DRAFT};}

~

\end{document}
```