# exactly same code works well on overleaf and does not work on my laptop, there seems to be something wrong in my local env, how to locate the problem?

Tags: pdfpages, watermark

I am running MacTeX on mac.

This [code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/516779/192089) works well on overleaf.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\filename}{input.pdf}
\newcommand{\watermark}{\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \node [red,opacity=0.3,rotate=45,scale=15.0] at (current page.center) {DRAFT};}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand={\watermark}]{\filename}
\end{document}
```

when I run this code on my laptop, where the `input.pdf` is in the same folder as the LaTeX file, and the output contains only the content of `input.pdf` without anything about watermark.

following is the whole log. could someone please take a look?

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=xelatex 2018.4.16)  17 NOV 2019 21:45
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**add_watermark.tex
(./add_watermark.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 2
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks14
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen103
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen104

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box26
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
Package: pgfrcs 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
))
Package: pgf 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 99.

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def
File: xetex.def 2017/06/24 v5.0h Graphics/color driver for xetex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen105
\Gin@req@width=\dimen106
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks16
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks17

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks18
))
\pgf@x=\dimen107
\pgf@y=\dimen108
\pgf@xa=\dimen109
\pgf@ya=\dimen110
\pgf@xb=\dimen111
\pgf@yb=\dimen112
\pgf@xc=\dimen113
\pgf@yc=\dimen114
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count88
\c@pgf@countb=\count89
\c@pgf@countc=\count90
\c@pgf@countd=\count91
\t@pgf@toka=\toks19
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks20
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks21

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-xetex.def

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-xetex.de
f
File: pgfsys-xetex.def 2014/07/09  (rcs-revision 1.11)

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvipdfmx
.def
File: pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def 2014/07/09  (rcs-revision 1.14)

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-p
df.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2013/10/10  (rcs-revision 1.13)
)
\pgfsys@objnum=\count92
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count93
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count94
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen115
\pgfmath@count=\count95
\pgfmath@box=\box27
\pgfmath@toks=\toks22
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks23
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks24
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count96
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.27)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen116
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen117
\pgf@picminy=\dimen118
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen119
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen120
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen121
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen122
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen123
\pgf@xx=\dimen124
\pgf@xy=\dimen125
\pgf@yx=\dimen126
\pgf@yy=\dimen127
\pgf@zx=\dimen128
\pgf@zy=\dimen129
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconst
ruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.29)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen130
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen131
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage
.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.24)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen132
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen133
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2015/05/08  (rcs-revision 1.46)
\pgfpic=\box28
\pgf@hbox=\box29
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box30
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count97
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicst
ate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.12)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen134
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransform
ations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2015/08/07  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen135
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen136
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen137
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.c
ode.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathproce
ssing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2015/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.43)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen138
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@max=\dimen139
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count98
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.18)

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2014/07/09  (rcs-revision 1.21)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box31
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2013/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretranspare
ncy.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2013/09/30  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2013/11/07  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.cod
e.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2014/03/21  (rcs-revision 1.35)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box32
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.
tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2015/08/03  (rcs-revision 1.13)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen140
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen141
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen142
\pgffor@skip=\dimen143
\pgffor@stack=\toks25
\pgffor@toks=\toks26
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.cod
e.tex
Package: tikz 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothan
dlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2013/08/31 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count99
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen144
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen145
\tikz@lasty=\dimen146
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen147
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen148
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen149
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen150
\tikz@figbox=\box33
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box34
\tikz@tempbox=\box35
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box36
\tikztreelevel=\count100
\tikznumberofchildren=\count101
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count102
\tikz@fig@count=\count103

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.cod
e.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2013/09/17  (rcs-revision 1.8)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count104
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count105
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count106
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count107

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.2)
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.sty
Package: pdfpages 2017/10/31 v0.5l Insert pages of external PDF documents (AM)

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count108
\calc@Bcount=\count109
\calc@Adimen=\dimen151
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen152
\calc@Askip=\skip43
\calc@Bskip=\skip44
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count110
\calc@Cskip=\skip45
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eso-pic/eso-pic.sty
Package: eso-pic 2015/07/21 v2.0g eso-pic (RN)

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/atbegshi.sty
Package: atbegshi 2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
)))
\AM@pagewidth=\dimen153
\AM@pageheight=\dimen154

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/ppxetex.def
File: ppxetex.def 2017/10/31 v0.5l Pdfpages driver for XeTeX (AM)
)
\AM@pagebox=\box37
\AM@global@opts=\toks27
\AM@toc@title=\toks28
\c@AM@survey=\count111
\AM@templatesizebox=\box38
)
No file add_watermark.aux.
\openout1 = `add_watermark.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box39

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/pdflscape.sty
Package: pdflscape 2016/05/14 v0.11 Display of landscape pages in PDF (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/lscape.sty
Package: lscape 2000/10/22 v3.01 Landscape Pages (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
Package pdflscape Info: Auto-detected driver: dvipdfm (xetex) on input line 99.

)
File: input.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use input.pdf>
File: input.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use input.pdf>
File: input.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use input.pdf, page 1>
File: input.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use input.pdf, page 1>
File: input.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use input.pdf, page 1>
File: input.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use input.pdf, page 1>
File: input.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use input.pdf, page 1>
 [1

]
(./add_watermark.aux)

LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 11506 strings out of 492970
 236619 string characters out of 6133938
 274231 words of memory out of 5000000
 15324 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3648 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 55i,18n,54p,426b,681s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on add_watermark.pdf (1 page).
```

Comment: What doesn't work? When scrolling through the log I don't see an error message.

Comment: did you run it again as indicated by `LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are right! Thanks a lot. Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it. a little bit explanation about why I have to run twice each time would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never ignore latex warnings, in this case

```
LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
```

Cross references never resolve until you have run latex at least twice, but LaTeX always warns if they are not resolved.  Presumably the watermark code is using the page reference mechanism to control its additions, I haven't looked at the code, just answering based on the warning you posted.

Comment: I'd suggest to question askers to always use `latexmk` or alternatives (`arara`?) to test their MWEs.

Comment: @OlegLobachev Then you assume that all users can install one of those. I have neither `arara` nor `latexmk` and not the right to install the necessary subsystems on my day to day computer.

Comment: Ok, let's amend a requirement to a suggestion. And I an quite stunned, I thought `latexmk` is a part of a quite basic system. But I am spoiled by MacTeX.