# Set a watermark where the content will be added latter

Tags: watermark, xwatermark, draftwatermark

I'm writing a document but now I'm just in the beginning of it, it's a draft phase. I already know the section names and how many pages each section will spam, i.e. `\section{Intro}` should have up to 3 pages. After that comes `\section{Objectives}`.

I would like to put a watermark and reserve the 3 pages for the Intro. Below is something I tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage{lineno,xcolor}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}

\begin{document}

\section{Intro}

\newwatermark[allpages,color=red!50,angle=45,scale=3,xpos=0,ypos=0]{DRAFT}

\newpage~
\newpage~
\newpage~

\section{Objectives}

This section contain only this text. It is not a draft and should not have the watermark.

\end{document}
```

But the watermark goes over the next section. Is it possible to watermark only a section?

Comment: Please complete your example so we can compile it. Not much point answering without knowing the class, at the very least.

Comment: Please edit to provide a complete example. Have you looked at any of the packages you've tagged this with? This does not seem engine specific, though.

Comment: Question edited. May I add something else?

Comment: You can edit again. Is that what you mean? Is there an option other than `allpages`? That seems not likely to do what you want!

Answer (score 1):

Directly for `xwatermark` package documentation, p. 4:

> The boolean options firstpage, lastpage, allpages, firstpage, oddpages
>   and evenpages, which specify the pages that should receive watermarks,
>   may be replaced by any of the options page=x, pages=x-y,
>   pagex={x,y,z}, where `x', etc., stand for any page number.

Let me know if this is what you're looking for.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage{lineno,xcolor}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}

\begin{document}

    \section{Intro}

    \newwatermark[pages=1-3,color=red!50,angle=45,scale=3,xpos=0,ypos=0]{DRAFT}% <-- watermark only for pages 1, 2 and 3

    \newpage~
    \newpage~
    \newpage~

    \section{Objectives}

    This section contain only this text. It is not a draft and should not have the watermark.

\end{document}
```

*Edit:*

You can set `\xwmwatermarkoff` if you don't want to specify the pages, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76157/101651):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage{lineno,xcolor}
\usepackage{xwatermark}

\begin{document}

    \section{Intro}

    \newwatermark[allpages=true,color=red!50,angle=45,scale=3,xpos=0,ypos=0]{DRAFT}% <-- watermark only for pages 1, 2 and 3

    \newpage~
    \newpage~
    \newpage~

    \section{Objectives}
    \xwmwatermarkoff
    This section contain only this text. It is not a draft and should not have the watermark.

\end{document}
```

Page 1 (also page 2 and 3 have the watermark):

[image]

Page 4 without watermark:

[image]

Comment: The undesirable effect I see with this approach is that pages are fixed. I would like to specify the section `Intro` is a draft no matter which is the page number, i.e.

Comment: @KcFnMi Have you look at my edit?